# Ctrl + click no longer works in Firefox

Tags: firefox

A few days ago, about when Firefox was updated to 3.6.21, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click stopped opening links in a new tab. How do I restore this functionality?

Comment: The current version of Firefox in Ubuntu is 6.0 - 3.6.x was not "a few days ago", but "many months ago". What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Sergey If they're still on 3.6.x, then I think they're using Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup.
Updated GreaseMonkey to 0.9.11 and that solved the problem.

Comment: Not sure what caused it to resume working, but it works now, after a restart.